# Geometric series involving the Laguerre polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, orthogonal-polynomials

Let put $\alpha=5$ and $x=3$. Consider the following set given by
$$M=\lbrace \; n \in N, \; \; 0 < |L_{n}^{5}(3)| < 1 \; \rbrace$$
Where $L_{n}^{\alpha}(x)$ is the generalized Laguerre polynomial defined by
$$L_{n}^{\alpha}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+n+1)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)\Gamma(\alpha+k+1)} \frac{(-x)^{k}}{k!}=\frac{x^{-\alpha}e^{x}}{n!} \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(x^{n+\alpha}e^{-x})$$
For the sequence $(|L_{n}^{5}(3)|)_{n \in M}$. I would like to prove that the series $\sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty}(1-|L_{n}^{5}(3)|)^{k}$ is convergent, i.e
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty}(1-|L_{n}^{5}(3)|)^{k} < + \infty$$
I would like to know if I could write the expression above as
$$\mbox{ for some } m > 0, \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty}(1-|L_{n}^{5}(3)|)^{k} < m$$
where $m$ is a strictly positive constant which does not depend on $n$. Please, I need some clarification on that case, because in fact geometric series are obviously convergent but the problem here is the index $n$ must not be involved in order to prove the statement in more explicit way.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-|L_n^5(3)|)^k=1/|L_n^5(3)|$. So, it appears that you want to show that $L_n^5(3)$ is bounded away from $0$, right?

Comment: Yes i want to prove that $1/|L_{n}^{5}(3)|$ is bounded for $n \in M$

Comment: OK. Then you can quite a bit simplify your question: remove the series and remove the set $M$, and just say that you want to prove that $L^5_n(3)$  is bounded away from $0$. ($1/L^5_n(3)$ is bounded by $1$ for $n\notin M$.)

Comment: But i want to prove that $1/|L_{n}^{5}(3)|$ is bounded for $n \in M$. Why you remove $M$?

Comment: You can leave your $M$, if you do not want to simplify your question. The explanation of why $M$ is not needed was given in the last sentence (in the parentheses) of my previous comment.

Comment: By the way, do you have a response to my answer to your previous question, at https://mathoverflow.net/a/418621/36721 ?

Comment: I don't understand your response

Comment: I just want to prove the boundness of the inverse of the laguerre polynomial