# Closeness of a rational approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, real-analysis, inequalities, asymptotics

> What is
> $$p_*:=\inf\big\{p\in\mathbb R\colon\,\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}n^p\,\inf_{k\in\mathbb N}
> |2\sqrt{3n}-9\pi/4-k\pi|>0\big\},$$
> where $\mathbb N:=\{1,2,\dots\}$?

In other words, I would like to know how small a real $p$ can be so that for some real $c>0$ and all natural $n,k$ we have
$$|2\sqrt{3n}-9\pi/4-k\pi|\ge \frac c{n^p}.$$
One may note that $p_*\ge1/2$, since $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n<n^{-1/2}$ and hence $\inf_{k\in\mathbb N}
|2\sqrt{3n}-9\pi/4-k\pi|<\sqrt3\,n^{-1/2}$ for infinitely many $n$, so that $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}n^p\,\inf_{k\in\mathbb N}
|2\sqrt{3n}-9\pi/4-k\pi|>0\big\}=0$ if $p<1/2$.

This question is related to this [previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419264/geometric-series-involving-the-laguerre-polynomials).

---

As fedja noted in a comment, this problem seems similar to the problem of determining the irrationality measure of $\pi$, and thus may be just too hard.

Actually, for my purposes it would be enough to know how $p_*$ compares with $9/4$: Is $p_*$ greater than, less than, or equal to $9/4$?

Comment: Something is fishy: as written, the answer is, obviously, $0$ because any positive power of $n$ would be a disaster: there are plenty of $n$ for which $2\sqrt{3n}$ is at constant distance from the given arithmetic progression with difference $\pi$. You obviously meant something else but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @fedja : Thank you for your comment. This is now fixed, hopefully.

Comment: I still believe that the first $\inf$ should be $\sup$ as it was and the second one $\liminf$.

Comment: @fedja : I think the set $\big\{p\in\mathbb R\colon\,\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}n^p\,\inf_{k\in\mathbb N}
|2\sqrt{3n}-9\pi/4-k\pi|>0\big\}$ is of the form $(p_0,\infty)$ or $[p_0,\infty)$ for some real $p_0\ge0$ and hence the supremum of this set is $\infty$. As for the $\inf_n$, replacing it by $\liminf_n$ will not make a difference, I think.

Comment: Ah, you also replaced the condition $<\infty$ by $>0$. I haven't noticed that. Then you're right, of course; my apologies.

Comment: Needless to say, the problem is very close to that of determining the irrationality measure of $\pi$, so I will be very surprised if somebody solves it completely...